# Can I concatenate a string with a subquery?

Tags: sql-server-2016

I don't even know how to properly word this question. I am trying to write a query that will look at Cases (status: closed), check if a note has been entered by a specific user, and if so, check if a note was added after that one (that note will state if the case was reopened or not). Here's what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT scr.CaseId, scr.AssignedSRIdent, s.RepFullName FROM dbo.SupportCaseRoot scr
INNER JOIN #comparison1 c ON c.CaseId = scr.CaseId
INNER JOIN #comparison2 c2 ON c2.CaseId = scr.CaseId
INNER JOIN dbo.servicereproot s ON s.SRIdent = scr.SRIdent
INNER JOIN dbo.SupportCaseNote scn ON scn.CaseId = scr.CaseId
WHERE scr.StatusId IN (4, 36, 37, 39, 28)
AND c.DateCreated > c2.DateCreated
AND scn.Description LIKE '%status%of%' + ' ' + (SELECT scs.Description FROM dbo.SupportCaseStatus scs WHERE scs.StatusId NOT IN (4, 36, 37, 39, 28))
ORDER BY scr.CaseId
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I am assuming because of the last AND statement and my feeble attempt at concatenation. I want it to look for "status of [all descriptions found]". Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some solutions:

- use 'top 1' or 'row offset' to returning single value in subquery or
- use aggregation function (like for ex. max) to returning single value in subquery or
- replace this subquery with a function returning single value

Answer (score 0):

The error here is the subtable returning more than one value.

Isolate the subquery and see the results you're getting. The subquery needs to return at most ONE result for it to be "concatenable".

Answer (score 0):

Try to match within the subquery, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT scr.CaseId, scr.AssignedSRIdent, s.RepFullName 
FROM dbo.SupportCaseRoot scr
INNER JOIN #comparison1 c ON c.CaseId = scr.CaseId
INNER JOIN #comparison2 c2 ON c2.CaseId = scr.CaseId
INNER JOIN dbo.servicereproot s ON s.SRIdent = scr.SRIdent
INNER JOIN dbo.SupportCaseNote scn ON scn.CaseId = scr.CaseId
WHERE scr.StatusId IN (4, 36, 37, 39, 28)
AND c.DateCreated > c2.DateCreated
AND EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SupportCaseStatus scs WHERE scs.StatusId NOT IN (4, 36, 37, 39, 28) 
  AND scn.Description LIKE ('%status%of%' + ' ' + scs.Description)
)
ORDER BY scr.CaseId
```